# C++ Pointers to arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

char strA[80] = "A string to be used for demonstration purposes";
char strB[80];

char *my_strcpy(char *destination, char *source)
{
   char *p = destination;
   while (*source != '\0')
   {
       *p++ = *source++;
   }
   *p = '\0';
   return destination;
} 
int main(void)
{
    my_strcpy(strB, strA);
    puts(strB);
 }
```

so my question here is that when i take out the portion:
    //*p= '\0';
it prints the exact same answer, so why is this necessary? from my understanding, \0 is a nul portion of memory after a string but since the array strA already contains the nul portion since its in "" is it really necessary?

Comment: You have to set the null terminator in the end, otherwise you will overflow the buffer.  Try copying the string back without setting `*p = '\0'`.

Comment: Imagine you were writing `puts`. How would you do it without the null terminator? (And not via a different convention that C doesn't use)

Comment: Even though strA contains '\0',  you are not copying it from it, as your loop  stops at that character (while (*source != '\0')).

Answer (score 0):

Your loop stops when it sees the `\0` and so it is not copied to the destination and the destination is not NUL terminated. Is that a problem?

- Not if your destination buffer is initialized to all 0s
- Not if your code is willing to deal with fixed length strings (so the `my_strcpy` signature would need to change to return the length)
- In general **YES** - the 0 terminated C string is such a common thing that not following the convention is asking for trouble,

Whether you 0 terminate or not the rest of the values will be the same as they were when you started. The 0 termination just makes your character array a "standard C string".

For arguments sake: Assuming you knew every string had space for 80 chars you could just do

```
for(int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
{
    dest[i] = src[i];
}
```

The effect is the same and assuming the source is 0 terminated the destination will be too.

Comment: So if i don't nul terminate,  will the rest of the stored values in strB will be 0? @John3136

Comment: @RostamMahabadi, Your `my_strcpy` function has no way of even knowing `strB` is being used in the first place. It could just as easily be an array of fully uninitialized data, or an array with no extra room, or the same array as the source. If you don't terminate it yourself, a large number of valid calls will start giving unpredictable behaviour if using the copied string. There's not even any information available to zero the rest of the destination for you or anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already know the importance of the null terminator, but the point is, **you defined `char strB[80];` in external namespace** (with static life span), which causes initialization of the array `strB`, which sets all bytes of it to zero. That's why you can't observe the difference （because even if you don't append a null character, the rest of `strB` already is).

Moving the definition of  `strB` makes this visible. `strA` doesn't need moving because it doesn't matter.

In actuality, this code

```
while (*source != '\0')
{
    *p++ = *source++;
}
// *p = '\0';
```

When `*source` reaches a null character, **it's not copied to `*p`**, so you need to manualky add a terminator for that.